# Tools for high-thrust trajectory optimization

Tags: orbital-mechanics, trajectory, mission-design, nuclear-propulsion

I've tried using some of the freely available tools for making pork chop plots to explore the potential of transfers between planets.

But as far as I can tell, these really are not designed for and do not work so well for transfers that use very high (impulse) delta-V and are far from the optimal launch window. At least one states this explicitly.

I understand that very-high-delta-V trajectories do not have the same sorts of local minima as normal ones, but is there a free-to-use tool out there that can automatically do this cleanly? Especially if a limit of delta-V can be the input?

Comment: How high-thrust & high-delta-v are we talking here? Still impulse burns, or the continuous "point and thrust" kind?

Comment: Impulse burns exclusively, pretty much the range from hohmann to hyperbolic retrograde solar escape.

Comment: There are [Lambert's Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_problem) (sometimes called Gauss' problem) algorithms out there that are "universal variable solvers" that can handle hyperbolic through multi period elliptical transfer orbits. I built one in MATLAB, which I can clean up and provide if you'd like

Comment: As a student, I've used [this](https://ai-solutions.com/dste/) one for free. I think a range for dV could certainly be an input, if you use the [optimizer](https://ai-solutions.com/_help_Files/optimization.htm) to explore. I see that the tool has a 7 day free use, if you don't have academic use status. I'm not endorsing it and in no way benefit from it, this is just a suggestion.

Comment: @pathfinder_EOS is it mathematically stable at high dV?

Comment: @ikrase I am not sure how out of ordinary the values of dV or launch windows you are considering, so its difficult to predict math stability without actually setting up the problem. Unfortunately I don't have access to the optimizer.

However, the only time I have had stability problems is when I attempted running a targetting loop with ridiculous initial guess values for an impuslive burn. If you encounter this, consider using a finite burn option, RK8-9 propagator and/or a better guess.

Comment: I think it may be useful to take a look at the CR3BP example as shown on [this](https://ai-solutions.com/_help_Files/interplanetary_smp.htm#achr_circularrestricted) page (which has pork-chop like plots too) and also maybe [this](https://www.sciencebuddies.org/science-fair-projects/project-ideas/SpaceEx_p029/space-exploration/interplanetary-spacecraft-maneuvers) one, which uses the same tool for a purpose similar to yours.
In principal you could also drop an email to their support, they're quite responsive. (Atleast thats what I've experienced) Hope this helps!